# IdentityServer / getAccessToken();

Tags: javascript, asp.net, identityserver4

I have been given a web application to debug.  Within, it appears to make use of identity server to handle authentication.
I’m trying to get it to authenticate my development machine.  To this end I have created a new client within the Identity Server.  In this it’s asking for a secret key.  It’s my understanding that this key has to be stored within the App / IIS somewhere.

The code looks like it get this key by this segment of code with app.js

```
if (oauthService.getIsLoggedIn()) {
    var claims = oauthService.getIdentityClaims();
    $rootScope.currentUser.userName = claims.sub;

    var accessToken = oauthService.getAccessToken();
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
}
```

My question is where is oauthService.getAccessToken(); looking for the secret key?

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Client secrets are currently specific to server apps only. The modern approach to oauth2 in client apps is to still use the oauth2 auth code flow, however, exchanging the code for a token is done without the [client secret](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#single-page-apps).

Comment: Most JavaScript apps use implicit grant flow there for do not need a client secret.  I am not sure i understand the question what exactly is wrong with your code?